# Add links to "More!" items on .../privileges/moderator-tools page?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

A list of lists of several classes of posts appears near the end of the [moderator-tools](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) page, as follows.

> **More!**
>
> This privilege also grants you access to the following lists:
>
> •    posts with extreme votes
>   •    posts with the most comments/views/edits
>   •    recently protected questions
>   •    recently closed/reopened questions
>   •    recently migrated questions

plus half a dozen other bullet items.  It would be useful to me if each of those items were hyperlinked to the list it mentions.  Can that be done?  Is there any technical reason not to have such links?  Or is there any other sort of reason?

Comment: One reason not to have them is that people without this privilege can visit that page - they'd then have links that error on them.

Comment: The text before the links says, "this privilege also grants you access to the following lists." It should be clear the links are accessible to who has the privilege.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The privilege pages are generated from Community Wiki pages present on Meta Stack Overflow; those pages are then pushed to the other Stack Exchange sites. In the specific case, the page is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools.

[image: screenshot]

If the privilege page is edited on Meta Stack Overflow to add links to that paragraph, then it would be possible to do what you are asking for. As the change would involve all the Stack Exchange sites, the request should be done on Meta Stack Overflow.

Once the privilege page is changed, one of the developers needs to push the change to the other sites.

Comment: Then such a change can't be made at the english.stackexchange.com level, I take it.  So far as you know, would I be better off asking moderators to migrate question to [meta.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), or posting a new question there?  If the latter, are there parts of the question that have to be changed?  (Also, unlike as in this meta, I don't know if it has been asked before in [meta.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).)

Comment: I would ask a new question on Meta Stack Overflow. I didn't find such question asked over there; if it has been already asked, there will be no warm: It will be closed as duplicate.